# How to submit a CFInput type=file within a CFDiv container

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I am submitting a file in a `cfdiv` container, but the value of the file is not submitting to the processing page. If I submit the file outside of the `cfdiv`, it sees the file value. However, if the file is inside a `cfdiv` or `div` container, the form field is undefined. I have also added the  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `cfform`, but it is still not working.

**UPDATE:**

This is the first page (index.cfm)

```
<div  name="loadcontainer" id="loadcontainer">
    <cfinclude template="homepage.cfm">
</div>
```

The homepage.cfm

```
<cfform name="school_create"   id="school_create" 
      action="pro_create_school.cfm"    
      enctype="multipart/form-data"  
      method="post">

    <cfinput size="50" type="file" id="school_logo" name="school_logo">
    <button  type="submit">Save</button>
</cfform>
```

When the save button is clicked, it doesn't see the `form.school_logo` value in the action processing page.

I have also tried using a normal `form` and `input`, instead of a `cfform/cfinput`, but the form is being loaded into another tab when submitted, instead of the div container.

Comment: What does your code look like? What happens if you use a standard form and input?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  @MattBusche Yes.. If i do that. if works but doesn't load in the <div container. I try using target on the form but it just load on another tab

Comment: You can start by stop using `cfdiv`, `cfform`, `cffileinput`, etc. The UI tags in ColdFusion are poorly implemented, way out of date and severely limited.

Comment: @IdowuRoseAwosanya - For next time, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That said, [file uploads are not supported within a cfdiv](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/requesting-and-presenting-information/using-ajax-user-interface-components-and-features/using-ajax-form-controls-and-features.html) *"...When you use Ajax to submit forms asynchronously from the page, you cannot use cfinputor[sic] input tags to upload files..."*.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for making me know that.. But are there any ways in which i can submit the input file in a div? Please.. Help with detailed process. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have my own work to do today ;-) Do a search on asynchronous file uploads. This is not something specific to CF, so there are a TON of articles and examples explaining what can/cannot be done with asynch uploads.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks. Grateful!

Comment: @ScottStroz if i don't use the 'cfform' it won't load the processing page in that div container..

Comment: You will need to learn how to do that the real/right way - using a JavaScript library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Submit the form both the `<cfinput type="file"..../>` and other form field in the form with ajax.

```
<script>
                        function validateForm() {
                            var x = document.forms["add_academic_year"]["start_year"].value;
                            var y = document.forms["add_academic_year"]["end_year"].value;
                            if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "") {
                                alert("Start Year and End Year Must be Selected");
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (y <= x) {
                                alert("End Year must be greater than Start Year ");
                                return false;
                            }

            console.log("submit event");
            var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("add_academic_year"));
            $.ajax({
              url: "pro_academic_year.cfm",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
              contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            }).done(function( response ) {
                // display response in DIV
                $("#loadcontainer").html( response.toString());
            })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                // display error in DIV
                $("#outputf").html(errorMessage);
            })            
            return false;

                        }
                        </script>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then drop the CF UI controls like `cfinput`. They are outdated and rely on a different JS library. Mixing JS libraries is asking for problems IMO. (Side note, if you are having trouble with code formatting, there are online tools like [jsbeautifier.org] :-).(http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Answer (score 1):

"File" is an incorrect "type" for a CFINPUT in earlier CF Versions (not sure what version you are using). I did check the docs and it is allowed in current versions.

Meanwhile, Instead change your CFINPUT to:

```
<input size="50" type="file" id="school_logo" name="school_logo">
```

Or better yet, get rid of `<cfform>` - you aren't using it for anything and you  don't need it. A good JS library (jquery) will provide you with better functionality for validation etc.

In this case you could easily do:

```
<form name="school_create"   id="school_create" 
      action="pro_create_school.cfm"    
      enctype="multipart/form-data"  
      method="post">

    <input size="50" type="file" id="school_logo" name="school_logo">

    <button  type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

And it would work as expected. Cfform is designed to provide simple validation functions in a native CF Fashion, but outside of tutorials and books explaining CFML almost no one uses it. When we see it used here at CF Webtools, we refactor it as soon as we are able.

Comment: Yes, they definitely need to use something else :) Sounds like the problem is they want to upload a file, *within a cfdiv*, which does not support asynch file uploads. ie The form itself submits, but the file is not uploaded with it.

Comment: @MarkAKruger Using a '<form' instead of a '<cfform' won't load the form in the '<div" container..

Comment: Hmm.... they reference CFDIV, but his/her examples don't show it. I was working off the example I guess.